# Custom Circle Button in xCode

Tags: ios, swift

So I made a custom button with a round image in xCode however whenever I click around the circle it still registers a click. Basically it is still picking up the transparent background of the image and registering clicks.
I have tried using layer.cornerRadius and layer.masksToBounds but neither seem to be helping.
Does anyone know what I can be doing wrong I'm pretty new to this?

ps i am programming in swift

Comment: The button is still square, it's just rendering as a circle. If you want to limit touches to the circle you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to subclass it and add a UITapGestureRecognizer and when pressed on it you have to calculate the distance from the button bounds center to the touch point, if its <= than button.width / 2 then its inside the circle.

Comment: Okay I've never dealt with making a UITapGestureRecognizer before. I found it and I put it in the storyboard but I don't really know where to go from there

Comment: You need to connect it to a function, @IBAction in storyboard.

Comment: Take a look at @hsafarya's answer which I updated to swift, thats pretty much all you need to add in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override UIButton's `pointInside:` method. Here is the working example, if there will be any question, write comment.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cj6w19rg03evadm/AABJx5iiWUGFxM-mcorX0MFEa?dl=0

UPDATE: In short , here is the pointInside:withEvent: implementation:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    let radius = self.frame.size.width/2
    let distance = sqrt(pow(point.x - center.x, 2) + pow(point.y - center.y, 2))
    return radius >= distance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question for rounded button you need to use **OBShapedButton**.

you can get it from below link:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/obshapedbutton

Currently what is happening is that you you ate creating image with round and keeping other area as transparent but it won’t make you button round.

To make you button round you need to set **Corner radius** to you UIButton exactly half of you height and width and set clipsToBounds.
But it’s tapable area won’t get changes.

But by using OBShapedButton it will make button of any shape based on image.

What OBShapedButton does is it makes the button of shape of image and excludes all the transparent part of image and make the shape of button according to image.

It can even make shape of button like:

[image]

Hope it solves your problem. If any query please let me know.